# ocgx and media9 (v0.48) incompatibility

Tags: media9, ocg

When compiling(pdfLaTeX) with media9 v.0.48 (22 dec 2014) the ocg doesn't work if \includemedia command is present (no error). Everything is fine when using older media9(27 sept 2013)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{media9}% Pour le son
\begin{document}

\begin{ocg}{A}{Ai}{0}   % 0: invisible,   1: Visible
      Text to Show
\end{ocg}

\switchocg{Ai}{Click here to show text} 
\includemedia[addresource=./Figure/5sec45.mp3,activate=pageopen,  flashvars={source=./Figure/5sec45.mp3 &autoPlay=true}]{\fbox{Play}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both `media9` package and `ocg-p` package add a PDF catalog. Only one is authorized and used.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This looks more like a "bug report" than a question. If you do have a question, please edit the post. If not, report this issue to the correct party. I suspect (hence "bug report" in quotes) this is not a bug, but a known limitation in compatibility between packages, because of Paul Gaborit's comment.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I could, perhaps, be willing to modify `ocg-p` to make it compatible with `media9`. Moreover, `ocg-p` needs to be overhauled, because its `ps2pdf` support is bugged. I once tried to contact the author, but he didn't respond.

Comment: @AlexG The problem is more general: how to complete (or create) the PDF catalog? This feature should be treated by a specific package.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I rewrote the ocgx commands. The code now works with the remaining engines and is `media9` compatible.

Comment: @AlexG Good job! But now, with your patched code, `ocg-p` (and `ocgx`) depends on LaTeX3 syntax and on `media9` (via the `\mix_pdfobj:nnn` macro). I'm not sure that the author of `ocg-p` agrees to include all these dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Packages `ocgx` (via package `ocg-p`) and `media9` both make use of OCGs (PDF layers). Since both want to write to the global `\OCProperties` dictionary within the PDF Catalog, they cannot be used together (without further action).

**Update:**

The recent package **`fixocgx`** is supposed to remedy this; moreover, it extends `ocgx` functionality to the **`dvips` -> `ps2pdf`**, **`xelatex`** and **`dvipdfmx`** routes (though a recent Ghostscript (**>=9.15**) is required for `ps2pdf` to work).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{fixocgx}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{media9}% Pour le son

\begin{document}

\begin{ocg}{A}{Ai}{0}
  \strut Text to Show
\end{ocg}

\switchocg{Ai}{\fbox{Click here to toggle text visibility}}

\includemedia[transparent,flashvars={source=http://www.openbsd.org/songs/song49.mp3&autoPlay=true}]{\fbox{\huge Play}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```